# Sometimes Getting empty DataFrame while using SQL query through pandas.read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas

The below code is working fine when I run it, but sometimes it returns empty DataFrame. The table contains 2 million rows.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("somedatabase.db")
exp = input("Enter Date")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT SYMBOL,TIME_STAMP,OPTION_TYP,STRIKE_PR,OPEN_INT,CONTRACTS,EXPIRY_DT FROM datatable WHERE (SYMBOL =? AND EXPIRY_DT =?);", conn,params = {sym,exp})
print(df.head())
```

What can I do to rectify this?

Comment: Someone Please help!

Comment: It may have to do with the time it takes to connect. you can add a line that puts some delay so you have enough time to create the connection, before executing the next lines of code.